Molecular quantum dynamics: How to prepare initial wave packets for potentials from ab-initio calculations
A follow-up question from: Molecular quantum dynamics: wavepacket oscillating more than I would expect.
I carried out an optimization CO2 using CCSD/cc-pVDZ, resulting in the standard D_{inf h} linear structure with an R(CO) = 1.16805990 Ang. From the equilibrium structure, I performed a harmonic frequency analysis, which yields the expected four modes: doubly-degenerate bend, symmetric stretch, asymmetric stretch.
 **********************************************************************
 **                                                                  **
 **                       VIBRATIONAL ANALYSIS                       **
 **                       --------------------                       **
 **                                                                  **
 **        VIBRATIONAL FREQUENCIES (CM**-1) AND NORMAL MODES         **
 **     FORCE CONSTANTS (mDYN/ANGSTROM) AND REDUCED MASSES (AMU)     **
 **                  INFRARED INTENSITIES (KM/MOL)                   **
 **                                                                  **
 **********************************************************************


 Mode:                 1                      2                      3
 Frequency:       672.30                 672.30                1379.17
 Force Cnst:      3.4293                 3.4293                17.9252
 Red. Mass:      12.8774                12.8774                15.9949
 IR Active:          YES                    YES                    YES
 IR Intens:       32.554                 32.554                  0.000
 Raman Active:       YES                    YES                    YES
               X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z        X      Y      Z
 C          0.870  0.156  0.000   -0.156  0.870  0.000    0.000  0.000 -0.000
 O         -0.326 -0.058 -0.000    0.058 -0.326 -0.000   -0.000 -0.000  0.707
 O         -0.326 -0.058 -0.000    0.058 -0.326  0.000   -0.000 -0.000 -0.707
 TransDip   0.180  0.032 -0.000   -0.032  0.180  0.000    0.000  0.000 -0.000

 Mode:                 4
 Frequency:      2432.96
 Force Cnst:     44.9106
 Red. Mass:      12.8774
 IR Active:          YES 
 IR Intens:      651.190
 Raman Active:       YES
               X      Y      Z      
 C         -0.000 -0.000  0.883
 O          0.000  0.000 -0.331
 O          0.000  0.000 -0.331  
 TransDip  -0.000  0.000  0.817

I generated a (CCSD/ cc-pVDZ) 2D PES cut along the bend and asymmetric stretch modes, and fit it to a potential for use in MCTDH using the potfit and chnpot functionality of the MCTDH code. It produces a reasonable-looking well:

From here, I use the relaxation functionality of MCTDH, which propagates an initial wave packet in imaginary time to produce the ground state of a system. My objective is to begin as close as possible to the ground state, so I follow the instructions on section 7.1 of the manual:
Begin manual section

End manual section
My attempt at an initial guess is a Gaussian function centered at equilibrium and at rest (x_0, p_0 = 0 for both modes). For the reduced masses and frequencies of the modes, I use the information for the vibrational frequency analysis carried out before.

Bend (m, w) = (12.8774 amu, 672.30 cm-1) = (12.8774 amu, 0.08335 eV)
Asym. stretch (m, w) = (12.8774 amu, 2432.96 cm-1) = ( 12.8774 amu, 0.3016 eV)

which makes my INIT_WF-SECTION look like this
INIT_WF-SECTION
 BUILD
 # Mode  type    x_0       p_o    frequency (eV)  reduced mass (amu)
   r      HO  0.00,Angst  0.00    0.301646,ev   12.8774,amu
   t      HO  0.00,deg    0.00    0.083354,ev   12.8774,amu
 END-BUILD
end-init_wf-section

When I carry the relaxation calculation, the initial guess is a tall, narrow Gaussian

compared to the much more spread out ground state that MCTDH produces upon relaxation:

My question is: how is the width of my initial guess so far off from the ground state that MCTDH produces?
The possibilities that come to mind are:

Perhaps I'm misinterpreting the mass and frequency required as input?
Im specifying the units wrong somewhere. I've specifically checked that all units of length and angles are in Angstroms and degrees in my potfit, chnpot, and relaxation inputs, as is consistent with the PES scans I carried out. Perhaps I'm missing somewhere but I cant think where.


The credit here ought to go to Prof. Meyer, who quickly led me to the solution to the problem. He suggested that there was probably something wrong with the kinetic energy in the Hamiltionian operator. Indeed - I had set it up as:
#########################################################
###      Hamiltonian for CO2 ground state well        ###
#########################################################

OP_DEFINE-SECTION
 title
 CO2 vibrational Hamiltonian
 end-title
end-op_define-section

LABELS-SECTION
 V=natpot{../potentials/PES_S0_CHNpot}
END-LABELS-SECTION

HAMILTONIAN-SECTION
----------------------
modes    | r  | t
----------------------
1.0      | KE | 1
1.0      | 1  | KE
1.0      | V
--------------------------------------------------------
end-hamiltonian-section

end-operator


Crucially, I was missing the following section:
PARAMETER-SECTION
  mass_r = 12.8774,amu
  mass_t = 12.8774,amu
end-parameter-section

which defines the reduced masses of the normal modes to use in the Hamiltonian. With that, my initial guess is still the narrow Gaussian:

but the relaxed product is much closer to it:


If you wrote this answer based on what Hans-Dieter Meyer told you, then I recommend for you to click "edit" then checkmark the "community wiki" box.
